# Annotate a function and detect when it is called at Runtime - Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, android, reflection, kotlin, annotations

Hello let me try to make this clear: I want to do almost the same thing the Android annotations do. For example :

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void someFunction() {
}
```

I would like to make something similar but at Runtime. Annotate a function and when that function is called, i make a treatment (probably using reflection) and depending on the result i proceed to run or not the annotated function. Something like:

```
@IsLoggedIn()
public void someFunction() {
}
```

The someFunction() function will be executed only if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do happens a lot in the Java ecosystem, particularly with Spring projects. What you will want to look at is [Aspect Orientated Programming](https://flowframework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/AspectOrientedProgramming.html) and most particularly how aspect orientated programming is achieved in [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

As you suspected this entails reflection to wrap the methods that are annotated, so additional logic can be preformed before or after calling the method. In the case you are interested in, an aspect can be written to check if the user is logged in before invoking the wrapped method.

Comment: Thank you the insight @Dean. I didn't know about AOP i'll check it out and give a feedback.